# LibGDX - How to get the pause character from a BitmapFont

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a pause sign on a .fnt file, which I want to set as a button on the right top corner, but I don't know how to access it.

Here I define the BitmapFont:

```
FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal("fonts/space.fnt");
font = new BitmapFont(fontFile, true);
font.getData().setScale(0.4f);
```

And in the game Screen I set this label:

```
 pause = new Label("??", textStyle);
 pause.setPosition(Settings.GAME_WIDTH - 20, 10);
 pause.setName("pause");
```

Is it possible to replace "??" for something, to reach the pause sign? Or do I have to take another aproach.

Thanks in advance,
Aleix Alcover

Comment: When you created the font that pause character took place of some regular character, so print the regular one to get pause sign.

Comment: My problem was that I hadn't created the font, and I didn't know that regular character. In the end, I treated it as an imatge with a Texture. It was a workaround, but it worked.
Thanks MilanG

Comment: You can use Hiero to create your own fonts: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Comment: Thanks, once more :-)